# How to find sum of digits of a given number (integer) in O(1) space and O(1) time?

Tags: arrays

Please check below code ,it gives me segmentation fault.

```
int sum_of_digit(int num){
    int sum =0;
    if(num!=0){
        int r = num%10;
        sum+=r;   
    }
    
    return sum_of_digit(num/=10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop your recursion somewhere. Every return in your function call sum_of_digit, you need a return whitout function call to stop the recursion.

```
int sum_of_digit(int num){
    if (num == 0)
      return 0;

    ...
}
```